# How to go from $d= \left(\frac{A\cdot B}{B\cdot B} B,A \right)$ to $d=\frac{|A\cdot B|}{|B|}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, analytic-geometry

I'm reading Banchoff/Wermer's: *Linear Algebra Through Geometry.*

I understand that the distance from a point $A$ to the line through $B$ is:

$$d= \left(\frac{A\cdot B}{B\cdot B} B,A \right)$$

But in the book, the author writes it as:

$$d=\frac{|A\cdot B|}{|B|}$$

But I have no idea on how he went from the first formula to the second. I've tried to write the vectors with 2 components and expand but had no success.

> I thought about the following:
>
> $$\frac{A\cdot B}{B\cdot B} B=\frac{A\cdot B}{|B|^2} B=\frac{A\cdot B}{|B|} \frac{B}{|B|}=\frac{|A\cdot B|}{|B|} \left[ \frac{1}{|B|} B \right]$$
>
> As $\displaystyle \left[ \frac{1}{|B|} B \right]$ is the versor of $B$, then It's norm is one. It seems that $\displaystyle \frac{A\cdot B}{|B|}$ is what gives the size of the vector because whenever we a versor, we can multiply it by $|B|$:
>
> $$\displaystyle \left[ \frac{1}{|B|} B \right] |B|=B$$
>
> And then $|B|$ is obviously the norm of $B$, but it seems that whenever we can write:
>
> $$|X| \left[ \frac{1}{|B|} B \right]=B$$
>
> Then $|X|$ is the norm of the vector. In this case, the norm of the vector is precisely:
>
> $$\frac{|A\cdot B|}{|B|}$$

Comment: The second one looks like the length of projection of vector $\vec{OA}$ onto $\vec{OB}$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection

Comment: The expression on the right hand side of the second formula is the square root of the expression on the right hand side of the first formula, because the fraction is a scalar that can be pulled out of the inner product, and $(B, A) = B \cdot A = A \cdot B$. Did you lose a square somewhere?